# How to Create JAPE Grammars Automatically?

Tags: nlp, grammar, gate

I am having great troubles with JAPE grammars.  I have a small token dictionary  for the words that needs to be matched with  5 types of  document. 
One dictionary for  one type: For example Job, the dictionary of the person would contain  `{ "Engineer" , "Doctor", "Manager"}`.  I need to read this dictionary a create JAPE rules for that.  This is my first try

Phase: Jobtitle
Input: Lookup
Options: control = appelt debug = true

```
Rule: Jobs  
(  
 {Lookup.majorType == "Doctor"}  
 (  
  {Lookup.majorType ==  "Engineer"}  
 )?  
)  
:jobs
-->  
 :jobs.JobTitle = {rule = "Jobs"}
```

Is there any way to  automatically create  JAPE rules that only for searching tokens in a dictionary to documents?

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use a standard gazetteer where the last parameter in .def file could have a custom type like "Doctor" or "Engineer"?
Something like: keywords.lst:Doctor:Doctor::Doctor

Comment: All is my example above. Use your keywords in keywords.lst and create definition like above in any text editor. Load this gazetteer to GATE and run pipeline. As the result you will see a new annotation created.